# What is the purpose of A_to_a in this string comparison?

Tags: c, char, comparison, uppercase, lowercase

somewhere in a code for comparison of two string I saw this:

```
#define  A_to_a  ('a'-'A')

...

for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {

    if (!(word[i] == (tmpP -> word[i])) && !(word[i] == (tmpP -> word[i] + A_to_a)) && !(word[i] == (tmpP -> word[i] - A_to_a)) {
        found = 0;
        break;
      }
    }
   
  if (i==n) {
    found = 1;
    break;
  }
```

I guess it wants to consider uppercase and lower case similr, but how does it work with the phrase A_to_a?

Comment: The correct way to do this is with the `tolower` function from `<ctype.h>`, e.g. `if (tolower(word[i]) != tolower(tmpP->word[i]))`

Answer (score 1):

`'a' - 'A'` is a simply an integer number. If you add this number to the upper case letter you will get the lower case letter.

1. `!(word[i] == (tmpP -> word[i]))` checks if they are not the same
2. `!(word[i] == (tmpP -> word[i] + A_to_a))`. `tmpP -> word[i] + A_to_a` converts `tmpP -> word[i]` to the lower case and the checks if it is not the same as `word[i]`.
3. `!(word[i] == (tmpP -> word[i] - A_to_a))`. `tmpP -> word[i] - A_to_a` converts `tmpP -> word[i]` to the upper case and the checks if it is not the same as `word[i]`.

If all three form non case sensitive comparison.

But good code should use standard functions `toupper` or `tolower`. Above code is simply not good.

Answer (score -1):

This is just a bad code.:)

For example instead of this if statement

```
if (!(word[i] == (tmpP -> word[i])) && !(word[i] == (tmpP -> word[i] + A_to_a)) && !(word[i] == (tmpP -> word[i] - A_to_a)) {
```

it will be enough to write

```
if ( !( toupper( ( unsigned char )word[i] ) == toupper( ( unsigned char )tmpP->word[i] ) ) )
```

that is more clear and safer.

The macro

```
#define  A_to_a  ('a'-'A')
```

serves to convert letters either to upper case or lower case. But it is unsafe and can produce an unexpected result used in the conditions of the original if statement.

For example if you have

```
char c = 'B';
```

then to convert this variable to lower case you can write

```
c - 'A' + 'a'
```

that is equivalent to

```
'B' - 'A' + 'a'
```

As `'B' - 'A'` is equal to `1` then `1 + 'a'` yields `'b'`.

The above expression can be written using the macro like

```
c + A_to_a
```

that produce

```
c + 'a' - 'A'
```

that is the same as written above expression

```
c - 'A' + 'a'
```

Comment: I think there is an error in your answer. By including parentheses in the `A_to_a` macro, order of operations ambiguity is eliminated.

Comment: @Chris What ambiguity are you saying?

Comment: The question specifies the macro as `#define  A_to_a  ('a'-'A')` rather than `#define  A_to_a  'a'-'A'`, so `c - A_to_a` produces `c - ('a'-'A')` rather than `c - 'a'-'A'`.